# I am trying to convert my sql statement into vba but nothing seems to work

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to convert mt sql statement into a working vba code in order to automate my queries. However, I seem to be getting run-time error 3075: syntax error (missing operator) in query expression(in bold below). Anyone can help please?

I've added my original SQL statement below. what am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

```
Function Create_Queries()

Dim ticker1 As String
Dim ticker2 As String
Dim B As String
Dim A As String

ticker1 = EUF12
ticker2 = EUG12

SelectSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT CurrentDb.Series," & _
"CurrentDb.TimeStamp, CurrentDb.Trade," & _
"CurrentDb.BidOrAsk," & _
"CurrentDb.BestPrice," & _
"**CDbl(DateSerial((CInt(Left([TimeStamp],4))),(CInt(Mid([TimeStamp],6,2))),(CInt(Mid([TimeStamp],9,2))))+TimeSerial((CDbl(Mid([TimeStamp],12,2))),(CDbl(Mid([TimeStamp],15,2))),(CDbl(Mid([TimeStamp],18,6)))))+CDbl(Right([TimeStamp],4))*1/24/60/60" & _
"AS [DatenTime Value]**" & vbCrLf
fromSQL = "FROM CurrentDb"
wheresql = "WHERE (((CurrentDb.Series) = ticker1) And ((CurrentDb.Trade) Is Null) And ((CurrentDb.BidOrAsk) = B) And ((CurrentDb.BestPrice)><0) And ((CDbl(DateSerial((CInt(Left([TimeStamp], 4))), (CInt(Mid([TimeStamp], 6, 2))), (CInt(Mid([TimeStamp], 9, 2)))) + TimeSerial((CDbl(Mid([TimeStamp], 12, 2))), (CDbl(Mid([TimeStamp], 15, 2))), (CDbl(Mid([TimeStamp], 18, 6))))) + CDbl(Right([TimeStamp], 4)) * 1 / 24 / 60 / 60) < 40939))"
orderbysql = "ORDER BY CDbl(DateSerial((CInt(Left([TimeStamp],4))),(CInt(Mid([TimeStamp],6,2))),(CInt(Mid([TimeStamp],9,2))))+TimeSerial((CDbl(Mid([TimeStamp],12,2))),(CDbl(Mid([TimeStamp],15,2))),(CDbl(Mid([TimeStamp],18,6)))))+CDbl(Right([TimeStamp],4))*1/24/60/60;"
SQL = SelectSQL & vbCrLf & fromSQL & vbCrLf & wheresql & vbCrLf & orderbysql

CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("Query1").SQL = SQL

End Function
```

SELECT [EU_201~1].Series, [EU_201~1].TimeStamp, [EU_201~1].Trade, [EU_201~1].BidOrAsk, [EU_201~1].BestPrice, CDbl(DateSerial((CInt(Left([TimeStamp],4))),(CInt(Mid([TimeStamp],6,2))),(CInt(Mid([TimeStamp],9,2))))+TimeSerial((CDbl(Mid([TimeStamp],12,2))),(CDbl(Mid([TimeStamp],15,2))),(CDbl(Mid([TimeStamp],18,6)))))+CDbl(Right([TimeStamp],4))*1/24/60/60 AS DatenTime
FROM [EU_201~1]
WHERE ((([EU_201~1].Series)="EUF12") AND (([EU_201~1].Trade) Is Null) AND (([EU_201~1].BidOrAsk)="B"))
ORDER BY CDbl(DateSerial((CInt(Left([TimeStamp],4))),(CInt(Mid([TimeStamp],6,2))),(CInt(Mid([TimeStamp],9,2))))+TimeSerial((CDbl(Mid([TimeStamp],12,2))),(CDbl(Mid([TimeStamp],15,2))),(CDbl(Mid([TimeStamp],18,6)))))+CDbl(Right([TimeStamp],4))*1/24/60/60;

Comment: Please show us the completed `SELECT` statement.  Add `Debug.Print SQL` on the line before `CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef`, run the code, and then go to the Immediate window (Ctrl+g) to see the statement text.  You can also copy that text and paste it into your question to make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: By the way, `CurrentDb` is not a good choice for a table name.  Can you rename it to something else, maybe `tblCurrentDb`?

Comment: Hi HansUp. Thanks for replying. I added the debug.print sql code and the error message that appears states:    object required. The line that was highlighted is:    CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("Query1").SQL = SQL      Im trying to make VBA pick up the table named [EU201~1] by using a variable. So tblCurrentDb would be a better choice?

Comment: The SQL statement you added to the question starts with `SELECT [EU_201~1].Series`.  But your VBA code builds one which starts with `SELECT DISTINCT CurrentDb.Series`.  And now you're reporting a different error message.  I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion to simplify your debugging process

1. Create a simple select query and try to run it
2. Use `debug.print` to ensure you have made a correct query to run
3. Use blank space instead of `vbcrlf`

Hope it can give you some ideas how to figure out the problem